# Fast TSC calibration failed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am trying to install ubuntu 14.0.4.2 32bit on my virtual box 4.3.28. When I insert the iso image as a virtual drive the startup of the installation process stops at 
[    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
and even after a millennium of CPU cycles nothing happens.

What should I be doing or what am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I have read other similar questions on superuser or stackoverflow but they all suggest that the error is not serious and that it should go away after a while, but it simply does not.

Please help me folks, like always.